# Abstract over parameter types in implicit objects or values?

Tags: scala, abstraction, implicit

Consider this application of implicit objects

```
trait Splitter[A,B,C] {
   def split(list: List[C]):(List[A],List[B])
}

implicit object PairSplitter extends Splitter[Int, String, Pair[Int,String]] {
   override def split(list: List[Pair[Int,String]]):(List[Int],List[String]) =
     (list.collect{case (a,_) => a}, list.collect{case (_,b) => b})
}

implicit object EitherSplitter extends Splitter[Int, String, Either[Int,String]] {
   override def split(list: List[Either[Int,String]]):(List[Int],List[String]) =
     (list.collect{case Left(a) => a}, list.collect{case Right(b) => b})
}

def splitList[A,B,C](list:List[C])(implicit splitter:Splitter[A,B,C]):(List[A],List[B]) = splitter.split(list)

println(splitList(List((1,"one"),(2,"two"))).isInstanceOf[(List[Int],List[String])])
println(splitList(List[Either[Int,String]](Left(42),Right("two"))).isInstanceOf[(List[Int],List[String])])
//println(splitList(List(1,2,3,4))) //won't compile
```

It works, but obviously isn't terrible useful. It's no problem to write this for concrete types like Int and String in the example, but I see no way to write an implicit object or val which abstracts over A and B.

Can this be done, and how? If not, is it reasonable to expect a language extension which has this ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's values (ie. vals and objects) are *monomorphic*, so there's no direct way of getting what you're after if you insist on the implicits being values.

But there's a straightforward alternative if they don't have to be values: you can use something which *can* be polymorphic, an implicit *method*,

```
implicit def pairSplitter[A, B] = new Splitter[A, B, Pair[A, B]] {
  override def split(list: List[Pair[A, B]]) : (List[A], List[B]) =
    (list.collect{case (a,_) => a}, list.collect{case (_,b) => b})
}
```

REPL session ...

```
scala> splitList(List(("foo",2.0),("bar",3.0)))
res5: (List[java.lang.String], List[Double]) = (List(foo, bar),List(2.0, 3.0))
```

Comment: D'oh! Somehow I expected I would get the infamous ambiguous error when I add the second implicit method (for Either), but obviously that was nonsense. Works like a charm!